# Syntax error: Unexpected keyword CREATE at [2:1]

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery

I'm getting an error when creating a table. can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

```
DROP Table if exists #PercentPopulationVaccinated
Create Table #PercentPopulationVaccinated
(
    Continent nvarchar(255),
    Location nvarchar(255),
    Date datetime,
    Population numeric,
    New_vaccinations numeric,
    RollingPeopleVaccinated numeric
)
```

Comment: I would guess if you placed a line terminator like `;` after each instruction it might help. So `DROP Table if exists #PercentPopulationVaccinated;`

Answer (score 0):

You are using a syntax for Microsoft SQL Server instead of Google BigQuery. Here is an adjusted syntax for Google BigQuery:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE PercentPopulationVaccinated
(
    Continent STRING,
    Location STRING,
    Date DATE,
    Population FLOAT64,
    New_vaccinations FLOAT64,
    RollingPeopleVaccinated FLOAT64
)
```

Comment: hows it. ive been tring to learn SQL  I started on the Microsoft SQL Server but got an error I couldn't get past....ERROR ;Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
Operand data type varchar is invalid for divide operator.

Completion time: 2023-03-12T12:23:38.3393328+02:00

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues with your syntax. I'd highly recommend reviewing the [DDL Docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language) when you have a moment.

1. BigQuery does not use `#` as a table prefix. Additionally, it's best practice to explicitly list the dataset you're creating the table in:

`CREATE TABLE my-dataset.PercentPopulationVaccinated`

2. You need to use `;` to separate each of the unique DDL statements. Alternately, you can combine the two with the `OR REPLACE` operator:

```
DROP Table if exists my-dataset.PercentPopulationVaccinated;
CREATE TABLE my-dataset.PercentPopulationVaccinated...
```

OR

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE my-dataset.PercentPopulationVaccinated...
```